# Dice number always shows 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I wrote a code to show the number of the dice on the screen but that does not happen, only the number 0 is showing.

[image]

This is my `Dice` script:

```
public class Dice: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static Vector3 diceVelocity;
    private static Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start() => GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    private void Update() 
    {
        diceVelocity = rb.velocity;

        if (Input.GetKey("left")) 
        {
            DiceNumberText.diceNumber = 0;

            float dirX = Random.Range(0, 500);
            float dirY = Random.Range(0, 500);
            float dirZ = Random.Range(0, 500);

            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

            rb.AddForce(transform.up * 500);
            rb.AddTorque(dirX, dirY, dirZ);
        }
    }
}
```

And my `DiceNumberText` script:

```
public class DiceNumberText : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static int diceNumber;
    private Text text;

    private void Start()  => text = GetComponent< Text>();
    private void Update() => text.text = diceNumber.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Where do you change the value of "diceNumber" I only see you setting it to 0.  `DiceNumberText.diceNumber = 0;`

Comment: What are you doing that should increment the number?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you trying to find the number of dice, or the value of the dice, in otherwords, which side is up?

Comment: Why does your screenshot have a bunch of marks on it that in no way help the user identify anything?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you thought `DiceNumber` would magically set itself to the right value, but here's how it can be done.

Attach to your dice 6 empty child gameobjects, we are only using them for their transforms. Place all of them along the 6 sides of your cube, at the same distance (eg, 100 units from the center along the respective axis). To get the desired side, simply loop through the 6 gameobjects and find the gameobject with the highest `transform.position.z`, as that side will be the highest in the air, thus facing up.

Call the method that checks which side is the highest on `Update()`.

```
public GameObject[] Sides;

private int GetDiceCount()
{
    KeyValuePair<int, float> highestSide = getHeightForSide(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < Sides.Length; i++)
    {
        if (isLargerThanCurrentMax(i))
            highestSide = getHeightOfSide;
    }

    return highestSide.Key;

    KeyValuePair<int, float> getHeightOfSide(int side) => 
         new ValuePair<int, float>(side, Sides[side].transform.position.z);
    bool isLargerThanCurrentMax(int side) =>
         highestSide.Value < Sides[side].transform.position.z;
}
```

Keep in mind, though this will work, this will have to be called every frame, including when it's in the air. You can either have this only start being called once it hits the ground, or be called once you detect the cube has stopped rolling (however you plan on detecting that, I'm just answering your one question, not gonna write you're whole program for you).

Also, note that I'm using `i < Sides.Length` not `i < 6`. This way, in case you ever decide you want to make more dices of different sizes than just D6, you can reuse this script. Except for D4. Those die are weird. And probably also not D2, but I don't think you were playing on adding coins into the game anyways xP

Comment: [Here's the math](https://pastebin.com/EKdgLrui) for orienting a D4 [arranged thusly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOVSJ.png) (and viewed from the top).

Comment: @Draco18s Well that's interesting. I guess there's two types of D4 though, there's [this corner type](https://cdn.thingiverse.com/renders/6b/88/92/4c/44/d4_preview_featured.jpg) which would work with your script, and then there's [this edge type](https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-70184/images/stencil/500x659/products/732/723/d4_op_re__47627.1343343347.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on) which wouldn't, and this is the kind I think of when I think of D4, though I don't know which one is more common.

Comment: I would imagine programming the "edge" type would be the exact opposite process, where it's whichever number has the lowest `z` value. I found [these D4](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/36/ca/7c/36ca7cd206fcd4ca99c96941d2ea522c.jpg) where they could use the same script as the other cubes, given their design.

Comment: Oh there's definitely both types. When I did my dice roller I chose corner type *because* of the way I was displaying the results (and I did orientation math for all the platonic solids). (And another way of doing a d4 is to use a d8 numbered twice, or a d12 numbered thrice).

Comment: That's so cool. Idk why, but I find dice very interesting. I think it's because what they symbolize: randomness and chance, and I feel like, to some extent, video games come from dice and cards.